# Translate text into functional dependency

Tags: dependencies

In an exercise I have the following text which should be translated into a functional dependency:

"A module realizes a business case and is developed by an author"

My reasoning is that the business case and author exist before the module therefore the author and business case determine the module:

author, business case -> module

However my script gives the solution:

module -> author, business case

Can somebody help why the latter is true and not the former?

Comment: Could there be multiple different modules for a given author and business case?

Comment: Probably..therefore author, business case -> module is incorrect..

Comment: "the business case and author exist before the module therefore the author and business case determine the module" That has nothing to do with what a FD is. Quote a definition & ask about where you are stuck using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a functional dependency X -> Y means that for a certain value of X you have only a certain value of Y, "A module realizes a business case and is developed by an author" means that for each module there is a business case (and only one), and there is one author (and only one).

So the only thing that you can say from this statement is the validity of the  functional dependencies

```
module -> business case
module -> author
```

or, equivalently,

```
module -> business case, author
```

No other information can be derived from it (in particular, we do not know if the combination of author and business case can produce a single module).